# Using an empty space in an Active Class

Tags: javascript

I got a little help yesterday with a project yesterday that contained the following line of code:

```
document.getElementById("test").className += " active"
```

At first I couldn't get it to work because I wasn't adding the empty space before the " active" part.  Once I added it the code worked fine.

Why do you need to do this?  Is this a JS thing?

Comment: Apparently your element already has a class, and changing `something` to `somethingactive` is different from changing it to the expected `something active`. Use [`.classList.add(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) if you want to avoid spaces.

Comment: The `class` attribute's value is a set of words (class names) separated by spaces. If you add letters to the class string, and it ends with a word, then you're just altering that class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of Spencer already explains the reasons behind the space. I just wanted to note, that reading and writing class names can be simplified using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). For example, just use the following code to add a class:

```
document.getElementById("test").classList.add("active");
```

And to remove it, execute:

```
document.getElementById("test").classList.remove("active");
```

Also note that you should add the JavaScript shim as defined in the link above to support Internet Explorer 8 and 9.

Answer (score 2):

Because many classes on an element for its class attribute are separated by spaces, you needed to add a space because you have one or more classes already on the element. For example without the space you would have:

```
class="fooactive" // A single class "fooactive" that doesn't exist
```

As in it will concatenate the two values rather than reading them as two separate classes. So you need to add a space so the `class` attribute will read them as separate classes:

```
class="foo active" // Two classes "foo" and "active"
```